# Mysql Loop through rows to check for rows till finds one with count of zero

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have looked thru many solutions that are similar but can not find one that meets my requirements.

I want to limit my users to creating more than two shortURL per url in a 24 hour period

people are abusing this and creating 10+ urls and its clogging up my database.  so i want to limit them to 2 per url and leave a message if they have  exceeded that

right now i have this check to see if how many they have done per url

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ShortUrls WHERE user_id='$user' AND vidID='$urlMe' AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

   echo "user created this many urls: " .$result->num_rows;
   if ($result->num_rows > 2) {
         // keep checking till find one less that 2
     }
```

Loop thru the database of urls and check if they used that same url more than twice in 24 hours. if they have not used that url more than twice in 24 hours they can create a new Shortened URL with that url.

EDIT the solution i used:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT tube.vidID FROM tube LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) c, vidID FROM ShortUrls WHERE user_id='$user' AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) GROUP BY vidID ) urls ON urls.vidID = tube.vidID WHERE urls.c < 2 LIMIT 1;";
$result = $conn->query($sql2);

if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
  echo "You can add a URL to this video: " . htmlspecialchars($row['vidID']); 
} else { 
  echo "All videos used up!"; 
}
```

Hope this can be useful to others

Comment: "this works great but i need to loop thru till i find a result less than 2 and then allow then to create a new one." Loop through what, the list of full URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to see which `vidID`s have less than two rows created in the last 24 hours by the same `user_id`?

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*) c, vidID
FROM
    ShortUrls
WHERE
    user_id = ?
    AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY
    vidID
HAVING
    c < 2
```

But if you know the `vidID` in advance, and you're only concerned with that one `vidID`:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    ShortUrls
WHERE
    user_id = ?
    AND vidID = ?
    AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

If you want to stop them if they've created more than two for **any** `vidID`, try this:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*) c, vidID
FROM
    ShortUrls
WHERE
     user_id = ?
     AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY
    vidID
HAVING
    c > 2
```

If the query returns *anything*, the user has created more than 2 for a single `vidID` in the last 24 hours.

If you want to get fancy:

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) c, vidID
    FROM
        ShortUrls
    WHERE
        user_id = ?
        AND time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
    GROUP BY
        vidID
    HAVING
        c > 2
) i
```

Comment: thats similar to what i have, but again i need to loop thru and see if that vidID has been used more than 2x in 24 hour. go to the next vidID till it finds one that has been used less that 2 x in 24 hours.  if there are none left then say "you exceeded" .  i have a list of available vidIDS they can use so i will know the vidIDS

Comment: Still not sure what you want. Do you want to check one particular `vidID`? Or do you want to stop them if they created more than 2 for **any** `vidID`?

Comment: i want  to stop them for creating any more shortened URLS of that vidID if they have already created 2 shortened URLS with that vidID  in  past 24 hours hours

Comment: Oh. Then use my second SQL statement. That query will return 0 if the user created no URLs, 1 if they created  URL, etc. for the particular URL. No looping required, just read the result of the query.

Comment: could you explain what is going on there?  what is the "c"?   i dont understand the  query in several lines

Comment: The c is used in the first SQL statement as an alias to the COUNT(*) column. That way i could filter the rows with the HAVING clause. But ignore that. You seem to want the second SQL statement I wrote since you're only looking up one particular `vidID`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142013/discussion-between-dynamite-media-and-dave).